Card flip animation in react native
Is there a way to flip my card based on buttons press inside the card in react native?
Like I have card that contains 2 buttons - Yes and No. On pressing, yes or no the card should flip and the flipped card with have button that may link to a new page on after being pressed.
The problem I am facing is the card flips but after flipping I am getting button interactions of state 1.
Is there a way to fix this.

Tried using react native reanimated, for flipping.

his is a simple flip animation generated and modified using ChatGPT. It utilizes React Native's Animated API along with basic styling and timing functions to create a flipbook-like animation effect. The animation rotates a flip card around the Y-axis, displaying a front and back face. When triggered, the animation flips the card, providing a visually appealing effect. You can adjust the animation duration and styling to customize it according to your preferences

you can add two buttons and  use a hanlde function to click button
and use state as True or False .which can decide when the animation is take places



import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import { SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, View, Animated, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  const flipAnimation = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;

  const startAnimation = () => {
    Animated.timing(flipAnimation, {
      toValue: 1,
      duration: 1000, // adjust the duration as needed
      useNativeDriver: true,
    }).start(() => {
      // Reset animation after it's done
      flipAnimation.setValue(0);
    });
  };

  const interpolatedRotateAnimation = flipAnimation.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 1],
    outputRange: ['0deg', '180deg'],
  });

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={startAnimation}>
        <Animated.View style={[styles.flipContainer, { transform: [{ rotateY: interpolatedRotateAnimation }] }]}>
          {/* Front face */}
          <View style={[styles.flipCard, styles.flipCardFront]} />
          {/* Back face */}
          <View style={[styles.flipCard, styles.flipCardBack]} />
        </Animated.View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  flipContainer: {
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    perspective: 1000,
  },
  flipCard: {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    backgroundColor: '#f00',
    borderRadius: 10,
    backfaceVisibility: 'hidden',
    position: 'absolute',
  },
  flipCardFront: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  flipCardBack: {
    backgroundColor: '#00f',
    transform: [{ rotateY: '180deg' }],
  },
});



